# Creating and finding records in Views

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

I am currently working on a reusable view, more specific a newsletter subscription view.

The whole point of this view is of course to let visitors sign up to our newsletter, therefor i have created a NewletterSubscriber model. The view consist of a input field and a button which triggers the following action in my view.

```
  actions:
    subscribe: ->
      subscriber = @store.createRecord('newsletterSubscriber')
      subscriber.set('email', @get('email'))
      subscriber.save()
```

This yields the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createRecord' of undefined
```

Which indicates that store is not available in my View, so what would be a proper solution to this?

I thought about creating a method in my application controller, and let the subscibe button trigger a action in that controller instead. However i don't feel like splitting the code of like that.

What would be the most elegant solution here?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be trying to do this in the View layer. You should be acting on this action in the active route.

> However i don't feel like splitting the code of like that.

You are supposed to split the code. That is the way Ember's MVC works.

Comment: So that would mean that i need to create the very action in all routes where i decide to use this view? That would result in a lot of duplicated code. I don't think you got point of splitting the code, i don't want to split the code from the view, because i feel like it belong together.

Comment: The action can be defined on any of the parent routes, too - I typically put actions like this on ApplicationRoute so that they can be triggered from any view. You can also put actions on (and access the store from) the controller, if you would prefer to re-use a controller subclass for this type of view. Then you could use `{{render "subscriber" subscription}}` or something like that to insert that view/controller pair into any template.

Comment: Thank you Nick, it was something like that i was looking for! Please make it a answer instead. :)